# Java Print Everything in Queue Using LinkedList and The Deque Interfaces

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm a little stuck here, I need your helpm here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Iterator;





class Customer {
       public String lastName;
       public String firstName;
       public Customer() {
       }
       public Customer(String last, String first) {
          this.lastName = last;
          this.firstName = first;
       }
       public String toString() {
          return firstName + " " + lastName;
       }
    }
    class HourlyCustomer extends Customer {
       public double hourlyRate;
       public HourlyCustomer(String last, String first) {
          super(last, first);
       }
    }

class GenQueue<E> {
   private LinkedList<E> list = new LinkedList<E>();
   public ListIterator<E> iterator = list.listIterator();
   public void enqueue(E item) {
      list.addLast(item);
   }
   public E dequeue() {
      return list.poll();
   }
   public E show(){
       return list.peek();
   }
   public void printQueueElements(){

   }
   public E isNotEnd(){
       return list.getLast();
   }
   public boolean hasItems() {
      return !list.isEmpty();
   }
   public boolean isEmpty()
   {
       return list.isEmpty();
   }
   public Iterator<E>   iterator()
   {
    return iterator;       
   }


   public E removeFirst(){
       return list.removeFirst();
   }
   public E getFirst(){
       return list.getFirst();
   }
   public int size() {
      return list.size();
   }

   public boolean hasNext()
   {
    return false;

   }



   public void addItems(GenQueue<? extends E> q) {

      while (q.hasNext()) list.addLast(q.dequeue());
   }


}





public class Jerald {

    public static void main(String[] args){



        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input1;
        String input2;
        int choice = 1000;




        GenQueue<Customer> empList;
        empList = new GenQueue<Customer>();
        GenQueue<HourlyCustomer> hList;
        hList = new GenQueue<HourlyCustomer>(); 


        while(true){

        do{

            System.out.println("================");
            System.out.println("Queue Operations Menu");
            System.out.println("================");
            System.out.println("1,Enquene");
            System.out.println("2,Dequeue");
            System.out.println("0, Quit\n");
            System.out.println("Enter Choice:");
            try{

                choice = sc.nextInt();



                switch(choice){
                case 1:

                    do{


                    System.out.println("\nPlease enter last name:  ");
                    input1 = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("\nPlease enter first name:  ");
                    input2 = sc.next();
                    hList.enqueue(new HourlyCustomer(input1, input2));
                    empList.addItems(hList);

                    System.out.println("\n"+(input2 + " " +  input1) + " is successful queued");

                    System.out.println("\nDo you still want to enqueue?<1> or do you want to view all in queue?<0> or \nBack to main menu for dequeueing?<menu>: ");
                    choice = sc.nextInt();

                    }while (choice != 0);



                     System.out.println("\nThe customers' names are: \n");

                     int numberOfElements = empList.size();




                     for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
                       Customer emp = empList.dequeue();
                       System.out.println(emp.firstName + " " + emp.lastName + "\n");
                       empList.enqueue(emp);
                     }

                     break;






                case 2:


                    if (empList.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("The queue is empty!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    System.out.println("\nDequeued customer: "  +empList.getFirst());
                    empList.removeFirst();
                    }

                    if (empList.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("The queue is empty!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    System.out.println("\nNext customer in queue: "  +empList.getFirst()+"\n");
                }

                    break;

                case 0:

                    System.exit(0);



                default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid choice");
                }

            }

            catch(InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.println("Please enter 1-5, 0 to quit");
                sc.nextLine();
            }

        }while(choice != 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Look at CASE 1, in the loop im trying to print everything that have been saved in the Queue. I dont see any errors but unfortuantely when I run it,after getting the users input, ending the do-while loop, it doesnt print whats inside Queue. Is it a problem with my Method? in the Deque Methods I have tested `poll() element() and peek()` bu that didnt help either. Anyway I'm stuck here and cant move forward, I don't know where the problem really is, I reread and reread my code I think its flowing enough. But what are your thoughts on this? How could I fix it? I asked this question after trying everything I could to fix the error but no luck. Please share your thoughts and fix.

I think it is the for loop in line 155, in case 1, that is giving the wrong output. Your thoughts?

By the way what I'm doing in CASE 2, is Dequeueing,

Comment: When you are debuggin at which line is something unexpected happening?

Comment: @Gildraths Line 155 in the for loop of case1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you are calling the addItems method:

```
 empList.addItems(hList);
```

I don't know why the `hasNext` method which is used by `addItems` is always returning false? This does not make sense, you need to modify the logic inside it. As a result of it being false, your code inside while loop is never called.

```
public void addItems(GenQueue<? extends E> q) {
      while (q.hasNext()) list.addLast(q.dequeue());
}
```

Comment: @johnhll: I have to make new methods for hasNext() and next() right? so.. hasNext() , returns true if next() would return an element rather than throwing an exception. If I were to translate this to code:

`public boolean hasNext(){
      if next() != null
      return true;
     else:
        throw exeption

}`

I'm kinda new to java, how do i actually make the hasNext() and next(), ive been searching for how, but on my case this seems a bit confusing

Comment: @Rekt: I dont know if you really need that hasNext method since you have access to iterator anyway where in you can use it to iterate over your LinkedList collection: public ListIterator<E> iterator = list.listIterator(); just edit your addItems method by looping through the given GenQueue via its size and adding each item to the list.